# O(nlogn)-time complexity

Tags: time-complexity, polynomials

Is there a $O(nlogn)$ time algorithm for computing $p(x)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^na_ix^i$ ?

I think with the method below I get O(n), but I need O(nlogn)
Hint: there's a way to calculate $x^i$ more efficiently.
This is exactly what I'm doing right ?

```
x = v

total = 0

for coef in coefs:

    total += coef * x
    x *= x

return total
```

Comment: Repeat this computation $\log n$ times and you get $O(n\log n)$ complexity.

Comment: But there are a few mistakes in your code.

Comment: @R.Jean Any algorithm that takes time $O(n)$ also takes time $O(n \log n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution (when fixed) indeed achieves the complexity $O(n)$ by computing the $x^i$ incrementally.

From a numerical standpoint, this is maybe not the best approach because of the accumulation of truncation errors along the multiplies. The power $x^i$ takes $i-1$ multiplies.

It is well-known that you can compute powers by successive squarings and products, and the power $x^i$ can be obtained with $O(\log i)$ multiplies. That will yield a total complexity $\sum O(\log i)=O(n\log n)$.

Now it is possible to combine both advantages, as follows:

- compute $x^0,x^1$;
- square $x^1$ and multiply with the above to obtain $x^2,x^3$;
- square $x^2$ and multiply with the above to obtain $x^4,x^5,x^6,x^7$;
- square $x^4$ and multiply with the above to obtain $x^8,x^9,x^{10},x^{11},x^{12},x^{13},x^{14},x^{15}$;
- and so on.

In total you will be performing $O(n)$ multiplies, and every power involves $O(\log i)$ of them.

Comment: "From a numerical standpoint, this is maybe not the best approach because of the accumulation of truncation errors along the multiplies." For even modest-sized polynomials, that's dwarfed by truncation errors along the additions. If $x$ is not close to 1, $x^i$ is orders of magnitude different from $x$ for sufficiently large $i$.

Comment: @Pseudonym: in fact this discussion is mostly academical. Except in "pathological" cases, one does not evaluate polynomials of a large degree.